# Solve require of es module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, swiper.js, remix

I recently used `swiperjs` to include a carousel inside my `remix` app.
It hit me with this error:
[image]

I searched for different fixes on how to resolve this but none worked.
The fixes I tried are:

- adding `"type":"module"` to `package.json`
- adding `serverDependenciesToBundle` in `remix.config.js`

Here's an example of my `remix.config.js`:

```
/**
 * @type {import('@remix-run/dev').AppConfig}
 */
module.exports = {
  serverDependenciesToBundle: ['swiper', 'swiper/react'],
  serverBuildTarget: 'netlify',
  server: './server.js',
  ignoredRouteFiles: ['**/.*'],
  // appDirectory: "app",
  // assetsBuildDirectory: "public/build",
  // serverBuildPath: ".netlify/functions-internal/server.js",
  // publicPath: "/build/",
};
```

This is the code I use:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
             <Swiper
                spaceBetween={50}
                slidesPerView={3}
                onSlideChange={() => console.log('slide change')}
                onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
              </Swiper>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer of this problem is the next:

`{
serverDependenciesToBundle:  ['swiper', 'swiper/react', 'swiper/react/swiper-react.js', 'ssr-window','ssr-window/ssr-window.esm.js','dom7'],
}`

This is because you need push all libraries using esm.